# compaq cq50 139wm wifi light blinking

Tags: dual-boot, android

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 on a compaq cq50 these computers have a light that show whether the wifi is on or off. The light turns blue when the wifi is on and red when is off but with ubuntu every time that I'm browsing the web this light just start to blinking red so I want to know if there is a way to stop these lights from blinking because at this point is driving me crazy?

```
 lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR5BXB63 (Foxconn) 802.11bg Mini PCIe NIC [103c:137a]
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks. Though it's probably impossible because this stuff is usually controlled by closed-source firmware. Just put some opaque sticky tape over the light if it's annoying you.